# Print lines of strings after a certain String in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have this code in bash that gets the last string in fileA.txt and compares it to fileB.txt within an if statement.

**fileA.txt contains:**
`[GRP2.0] 10221 ==== 2013-03-10 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10222 ==== 2013-03-11 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10223 ==== 2013-03-12 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10224 ==== 2013-03-13 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10225 ==== 2013-03-14 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`

**fileB.txt contains:**

`[GRP2.0] 10223 ==== 2013-03-12 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10224 ==== 2013-03-13 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10225 ==== 2013-03-14 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10226 ==== 2013-03-15 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10227 ==== 2013-03-16 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10228 ==== 2013-03-17 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10229 ==== 2013-03-18 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10230 ==== 2013-03-19 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`

Question:
`$file` is `fileA.txt`

Is there a way to echo everything after $stringCompared in fileB.txt?

**`$stringCompared` has this:**
 `[GRP2.0] 10225 ==== 2013-03-14 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`.

**Expected Output in fileC.txt:**
`[GRP2.0] 10226 ==== 2013-03-15 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10227 ==== 2013-03-16 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10228 ==== 2013-03-17 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10229 ==== 2013-03-18 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`
`[GRP2.0] 10230 ==== 2013-03-19 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin`

```
lastString=$(tac "$file" |egrep -m1 '.')
        stringCompared=$lastString
        if grep -Fxq "$lastString" /folder/fileB.txt; then

        tac /folder/fileB.txt | awk -v savedString="$stringCompared" '1; $0 ~ savedString {exit}' | tac

        printf "$savedString\n"
        echo "$savedString" | tee /folder/temp.txt
```

I also tried using another route:

```
savedString=$(sed '1,/'"$stringCompared"'/d' /folder/fileB.txt)
```

But it's not working, any tips?

Comment: You might tell people like me that you use the construction with `tac` so you will skip empty lines at the end of $file.

Comment: Aside: `tac "$file"`, not `tac $file`; otherwise, you get string-splitting and globbing behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tac` to process the file from the end, print up to the match and then `tac` back:

```
tac file | awk '/match/ {exit} 1' | tac
```

#### Test

```
$ seq 10 | tac | awk '/5/ {exit}1' | tac
6
7
8
9
10
```

or

```
$ seq 10 | tac | awk '1; /5/ {exit}' | tac
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

if you want to also print the matched line.

Comment: tac /work/fileB.txt | awk '/$lastString/ {exit} 1' | tac, if i put in the actual word to start on, it works, but when i want it to be dynamic, it doesnt work. it prints out everything in fileB.txt. Any tips?

Comment: @JohnSmith you need to give the variable to awk: `awk -v mypattern="$lastString" '$0 ~ mypattern {exit}1'`

Comment: what is mypattern based from your example. And where should i put awk -v mypattern="$lastString" '$0 ~ mypattern {exit}1' in your example ?

Comment: @JohnSmith in my case I would say `seq 10 | tac | awk -v mypattern=5 '1; $0 ~ mypattern {exit}' | tac`.

Comment: **tac /folder/fileB.txt | awk -v tempVariable="$stringCompared" '1; $0 ~ tempVariable {exit}' | tac ** this is what I have, but it's not working

Comment: @JohnSmith what does `$stringCompared` contain?

Comment: $stringCompared is the variable that has the matched string, in your example, it is the 5.

Comment: @JohnSmith but I mean, in your case, what value does it have? Because the exact syntax `seq 10 | tac | awk -v mypattern=5 '1; $0 ~ mypattern {exit}' | tac` works. I am trying to guess what is missing in your code to make it work.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it helps. and $stringCompared has [GRP2.0] 10225 ==== 2015-04-16 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin

Comment: @JohnSmith we are missing info here. Try to simplify the problem, because we don't know what is the content of the fileB, we don't know nothing. Reduce problem to the very basic so that you know what fails and what is ok.

Comment: I updated the question, I tried using your solution, but it was giving me all values from 10221 - 20230.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{lastStr=$0; next} !p && p=index($0, lastStr){next} p' fileA.txt fileB.txt
[GRP2.0] 10226 ==== 2013-03-15 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin
[GRP2.0] 10227 ==== 2013-03-16 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin
[GRP2.0] 10228 ==== 2013-03-17 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin
[GRP2.0] 10229 ==== 2013-03-18 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin
[GRP2.0] 10230 ==== 2013-03-19 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin
```

Comment: @anuphava i tried your solution but it is not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v s="$(tail -1 fileA.txt)" 'f; s==$0{f=1}' fileB.txt

[GRP2.0] 10226 ==== 2013-03-15 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin
[GRP2.0] 10227 ==== 2013-03-16 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin
[GRP2.0] 10228 ==== 2013-03-17 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin
[GRP2.0] 10229 ==== 2013-03-18 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin
[GRP2.0] 10230 ==== 2013-03-19 10:55:26-Custom field deleted,fields,admin
```

extract the last line of fileA and assign to awk variable s, when a line is equal to s in fileB set the flag f, print lines for set flag.